# Bad return status for module build on kernel: 3.2.0-56-generic-pae

Tags: 12.04, installation, dpkg

```
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS
Release:    12.04
Codename:   precise


Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 3.2.0-56-generic-pae (i686)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/alsa-hda/0.201204101019~maverick1/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing alsa-hda-dkms (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 10
```

How can I fix this?
This worked (sudo apt-get purge alsa-hda-dkms ), Thanks,  new to this but not afraid to try.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Maverick is a obsolete version.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get purge alsa-hda-dkms
```

then install the program again.

Answer (score 1):

Open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>. Write the following command in the terminal and follow the onscreen instructions.

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-generic-pae linux-headers-generic-pae
```

It will reinstall those packages. It may help.